# Ionic - $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction didn't destroy

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, back-button

I'm created one side menu project. It has 3 HTML files: firstPage.html contains button NEXT (go to secondPage.html). Same as secondPage.html that contains button NEXT (go to thirdPage.html) and for thirdPage.html NEXT button (go to firstPage.html). Every html has their own controller.

I followed [this link](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-handling-android-back-button-like-a-pro/) in handling my back button action for Android device. It worked but for already registered back button didn't destroy after I changed my state.

Based on my codes below, the result was when I clicked android back button at firstPage.html, its prompt the alert. Then I clicked NEXT button in firstPage.html then directly go to secondPage.html. When I clicked android back button in that page, its also prompt me the alert. Eventhough the 'TheSecondController' didn't have '$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction'. Same with thirdPage.html.

Here is my code:

**Javascript: app.js**

```
.state('app.firstPage', {
      url: '/firstPage',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/firstPage.html',       
          controller: 'TheFirstController'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.secondPage', {
      url: '/secondPage',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/secondPage.html',     
          controller: 'TheSecondController'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.thirdPage', {
      url: '/thirdPage',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/thirdPage.html',
          controller: 'TheThirdController'
        }
      }
    })
```

**HTML: firstPage.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="First">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>First</h1>
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" ui-sref="app.secondPage">Next</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**HTML: secondPage.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Second">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Second</h1>
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" ui-sref="app.thirdPage">Next</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**HTML: thirdPage.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Third">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Third</h1>
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" ui-sref="app.firstPage">Next</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Javascript: TheFirstController.js**

```
.controller('TheFirstController', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {  

    var deregisterFirst = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
      function() {
        if (true) { // your check here
          $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: 'System warning',
            template: 'Are you sure you want to exit?'
          }).then(function(res) {
            if (res) {
              ionic.Platform.exitApp();
            }
          })
        }
      }, 100
    );

    $scope.$on('$destroy', deregisterFirst);
})
```

**Javascript: TheSecondController.js**

```
.controller('TheSecondController', function() {  

    //Allow user to go to previous page
})
```

**Javascript: TheThirdController.js**

```
.controller('TheThirdController', function() {   

    //Allow user to go to previous page

});
```

Please anyone help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction()` function registers the action for the whole Application, not specific to a page. `$ionicPlatform` is a service created by Ionic so it is a singleton (as all angular services are) therefore there is only one instance of it in the app.

So when you set the `registerBackButtonAction` in one controller it sets it for the whole app.

If you want it to exit only if you're on the first app, you have to add an `if()` on the state name.
Something like

```
if($state.current.name === 'app.firstPage'){
  //your code here
}
```

The same way the guide you followed did it.

Comment: Oh really, this is what I did 
`if($state.current.name === 'app.firstPage'){
                $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title: 'System warning',
                    template: 'Are you sure you want to exit?'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    if (res) {
                      ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                    }
                  })
            }
          
          else{
              return false;
          }` but when I'm clicked android back button in  secondPage.html and thirdPage.html, it didn't go to previous page. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its really help. The problem now solved by putting `$ionicHistory.goBack()` at `else{ $ionicHistory.goBack(); }` .